# Read file from the current folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've node program which should run and during runtime read some hidden file
`.env.json` or `env.json`.  (not hidden file)

I've tried to print the following in the program which needs to read it:

```
dirname:  /Users/i012344/projects/rs/deploy
fileName:  /Users/i012344/projects/rs/deploy/deploy/index.js
process.argv[1]:  /Users/i012344/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/yo
```

My running program called is: `deploy/index.js`

But I **dont need this** path as this print the location of the current executable program, I need to read a file from the current folder that I run
my program.

e.g.

```
/Users/i012344/projects/app1/.env.json
```

Now I run my program inside the `app1` folder and needs to get the content of the `.env.json` file, how can I do it?

when I print

`console.log("process.cwd(): ", process.cwd());`

**I got** `"/Users/i012344/projects"`

**I want:** `/Users/i012344/projects/app1`

when running

```
 let filePath = path.join(__dirname, ".env.json");

  console.log("ft: ",filePath);
```

I got error as it search for it in the wrong place

```
  fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: "utf-8"}, function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("received data: " + data);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });



{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Users/i012344/projects/rs/deploy']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   '/Users/i012344/projects/rs/deploy/index.js/.env.json' }
```

I dont understand why it's happen as it's just like to a program which needs to read `package.json` as the package.json is in some generated project.

**I doesnt works also for non-hidden file**, not sure what Im missing here..., it should be rather simple, **just read file from where your application is running**

isn't it possible?

Comment: Your  `fs.readFile()` should work. Whats the output of `console.log("ft: ",filePath);`?